# How to fix warning after migration to xcode 11

Tags: ios13, xcode11, xcode11.1

I need help in resolving these warnings after I migrated to Xcode 11. The warnings are as follows:

> Unsupported use of UIKit API off the main thread:
>   UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() Unsupported use of UIKit API
>   off the main thread: UIAccessibilityIsAssistiveTouchRunning()
>   Unsupported use of UIKit API off the main thread:
>   UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled() Unsupported use of UIKit API
>   off the main thread: UIAccessibilityIsAssistiveTouchRunning()
>   Unsupported use of UIKit API off the main thread:
>   UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled()

Comment: If you are using firebase, it looks like this may have something to do with it - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4156

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying UI off the main thread. Wrap the calls to the listed methods in your code in `DispatchQueue.main` blocks:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  // code goes here
}
```

If you want to learn more about `DispatchQueue.main` I wrote a blog post about it recently: [link](https://www.donnywals.com/appropriately-using-dispatchqueue-main/)